# Is there a way to bind a DatagramSocket to any port on a specific nic or if I specify the nic I have to specify the port?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

Is that just impossible in Java? The DatagramSocket.bind method has to take either NULL or a IP:PORT. You cannot just pass an IP describing the NIC and let the PORT be chosen automatically. Kind of does not make sense unless I am missing something.

Comment: Take a look at DatagramSocket's constructors: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a port number of zero, or omit it as suggested by Mike Q. In both cases the system will allocate a port for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default constructor of `DatagramSocket`. This will bind to any port. You don't have to use the bind method.

Comment: I am using NIO, so I am not using the constructor but: channel = DatagramChannel.open();